# Wi-Fi и Делфи

Tags: delphi, wifi

Как связать два ноутбука с поддержкой wi-fi? Имея две программы на делфи, с одной на другую передать текст. 1-я программа имеет едит, 2-я - лейбл. Вводится в едит текст и нажимается кнопка, на 2й программе этот текст должен отобразится в лейбле.

Для подключения ноутбуков используется роутер. Как сделать такого рода сеть? Будет использоватся 1 сервер и 5 клиентов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это два совершенно не связанных между собой вопроса.

Сеть можно организовать двумя способами: ad-hoc (одноранговая, начиная с ХР нативно поддерживается), или с точкой доступа - на одном из ноутбуков организуется программная точка доступа (С помощью соответствующих утилит - у каждого производителя они свои, или на Win7 с помощью netsh за пару-тройку команд). После чего образуется обычная локальная сеть.

А примеров в интернете клиент-серверных приложений на делфи 100500 штук. Одна программа - клиент, другая - сервер. Клиент по известному адресу цепляется к серверу и отправляет/получает всё, что хочет...

Если вы хотите использовать Wi-Fi сам о себе, без организации сети, то это очень сложно и, думаю, мало какой драйвер это позволит.